# Is there any difference between Request.Cookies(name) and Request.Cookies.Get(name)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

As both of them can be used for retrieving cookie through `name` string, I would like to know if there is any difference between them.

Comment: The documentation for the `Get` method says that it creates a cookie with the specified name if none exists, while the documentation for the `Item` property, which your first example uses implicitly, does not.  I don;t know whether that means that it doesn't create one or whether it's an oversight.  You could test to find out.  Otherwise, they are effectively the same, although `Item` can be used equivalently to `Set` as well, being a read/write property.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to answer a question like this yourself, for the .NET Framework, is to make use of the [Microsoft Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/). This lets you see and navigate through the source for the .NET Framework.

Looking at this, [`Request.Cookies`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,cbd44ac64c01e796) returns an [`HttpCookieCollection`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpCookieCollection.cs,b43f6eadadf1c04e) and `Request.Cookies.Get` is therefore a method on `HttpCookieCollection`.

The most useful part of the code is for the indexer on `HttpCookieCollection` that retrieves a cookie by name:

```
public HttpCookie this[String name]
{
    get { return Get(name);}
}
```

As you can see from that, this calls into the `Get(string name)` method, meaning that using the `Request.Cookies(name)` indexer is fundamentally the same as using `Request.Cookies.Get(name)` as one calls the other.

It is worth mentioning that anything you see here is an **implementation detail** that's subject to change. You should rely on documented behaviour, not on anything you discover through digging through the code, no matter how informative and interesting it is!